# como puedo crear un snippet para rendondear una variable en php

Tags: wordpress, php7, wordpress-plugin

tengo una variable de un plugin en wordpress que despliega un precio en el carrito, el problema es que el numero tiene como 6 decimales, yo quiero redondear el los decimales de esa variable a 2 decimales. estaba tratando de hacer un snippet, pero creo q no funciono

```
round(float $PointPriceLabel, int $precision = 0, int $mode = PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP): float
```

Comment: Puedes ampliar mas información, con snippet hablas de crear un shortcode? cuando obtienes el precio del plugin, cual es la salida de texto, te lo muestra ya con decimales, muestra texto o el simbolo de $ antes del precio? y que error causa tu codigo?

Comment: mi moneda es el colon costarricense, el precio es desplegado tanto en Colon como en Puntos, en todo el ecommerce esta redondeado, tanto los colones como el plugin de puntos a dos decimales. pero a la hora de agregar el producto al carrito, el carrito muestra como 10 decimales, segund la conversion, lo que quiero hacer es un snippet en php, o en js que le diga a la variable $PointPriceLabel (que es la variables que sale con exceso de decimales) que redondee los decimaes a 2, puede probarlo: https://woocommerce-467967-2162196.cloudwaysapps.com/product/pizza-margarita